# Send message to discord using requests not working

Tags: python, python-requests, discord

I created code to send messages to channel I want but there is a problem that it send message only one time and for next message we have to wait a little bit although all requests are returning correct response each time. I can consectively send message to two channels but one message in like 2-3 minutes to single channel. Am I doing something wrong or it is there some new way discord blocks the message. Please help.

```
import requests

token = ""
channel_id = ""

cookies = {
    ...
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    # 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    # Already added when you pass json=
    # 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': token,
    'X-Super-Properties': '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',
    'X-Discord-Locale': 'en-US',
    'X-Debug-Options': 'bugReporterEnabled',
    'Origin': 'https://discord.com',
    'Alt-Used': 'discord.com',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://discord.com/channels/@me/' + channel_id,
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
}

json_data = {
    'content': 'message',
    'nonce': '1000213022410539008',
    'tts': False,
}

response = requests.post(f'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channal_id}/messages', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, json=json_data)
print(response.json())
```

I would like to explain it more. I can message many persons but can not message same person twice for a period of 4-5 minutes. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error you get when Discord "blocks" your message?

Answer (score 2):

Sending messages on Discord is different from reading messages or really most other requests because it requires you to be connected to the [Gateway](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#connecting-to-the-gateway), a websocket which sends updates depending on what you request. After you connect the request you are making will finally go through.

Also make sure your `Authorization` header is in the form of `Bot <token>` instead of just `<token>`

Comment: Can you provide working code

Comment: Also I have been using it like this two months before. It worked fine and I could do as many messages I wanted

Comment: Working code is hard to provide as authenticating with the Gateway is not something I have done in python, and it is a bit complicated. With your edits thought it seems like this is a problem with Discord rate limiting perhaps? Make sure that you ware not making extra requests which you do not know about, as that might cause problems with messaging, Other than that it appears to be something up with the discord servers, as your requests look good.

Comment: It is not rate limiting because I am getting correct response with 200 status code and also I can message other guys but not the same guy twice or more with in 5 mins. I tried to resend the request using developers tool while login, it also did not worked

Comment: If the response you are getting back from discord is normal then I suggest opening a bug report on discord because this seems like a server issue.

Comment: They will open case on me for spamming . The difference I found was the refere policy was unsafe- url while making request using script or resending the request from developer's tool

Answer (score 1):

I think the variable name in the `requests.post()` was misspelled, but putting that aside, there's a lot of unnecessary headers and cookies.
Here's my code:

```py
import requests

token = "<YOUR_TOKEN>"
message = "Hello World!"
channel_id = "896155634372861982"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0',
    'Authorization': token
}

json_data = {
    'content': message
}

response = requests.post(f"https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channel_id}/messages", headers=headers, json=json_data)
print(response)
```

The only two headers I kept are the `User-Agent` and `Authorization` although I don't think the `User-Agent` is needed, but it's probably a good idea so your requests aren't *too* suspicious.
Also, make sure to change your channel_id.
I also completely removed the cookies, and unnecessary json data.

Comment: Did you tried the code. I cannot try it but I added those headers from original request so this cannot be the possible solution. Also discord strictly check cookies and headers

Comment: @farhan-jatt Yeah I tried the code and it worked. Discord only checks for the `Authorization:` header.

Comment: @farhanjatt Why would Discord check the cookies? A bot token is enough to verify who you are. Are you sure you're not using a user token or something like that?

Comment: @farhanjatt Please try using the bare minimum number of headers. It's possible one of your headers is interfering.

Answer (score 1):

Best method I found is to use the discord package.

```
pip install discord.py
```

Then in your script/program:

```
from discord import Webhook, RequestsWebhookAdapter

webhook = Webhook.from_url("https://discord.com/api/webhooks/ **Application ID Goes Here**/**Webhook ID Goes Here**", adapter=RequestsWebhookAdapter())
webhook.send(**Your variables / data goes here**)
```

https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/

Just these two lines of code does it for me. You can manage your Discord application here to find your Application ID: https://discord.com/developers/applications

Your webhook ID you can set up in Discord in your Channel > Server Settings > Integrations

Answer (score 0):

I’ve faced the same problem. In my case, the solution was to change the value nonce to a random value before sending every message.

```
json_data = {
    'content': 'message',
    'nonce': str(random.randint(10**18, 10**18 + 2*(10**17))),
    'tts': False,
}
```